# How to get specific set of objects from list of objects

Tags: c#, linq

```
List<objects> MyObjects = GetobjectsfromList(otherlist);
```

The list of MyObjects I am working with have multiple properties

```
String name;

String locationInfo;

String otherObjectName;

DateTime date1;

DateTime date2;
```

(etc.)

Contained in MyObjects are things like this:

```
Obj1 (name1, location1, otherobjectname1, date1, date2)

Obj2 (name2, location2, otherobjectname1, date4, date7)

Obj3 (name3, location3, otherobjectname1, date6, date9)

Obj4 (name4, location6, otherobjectname2, date1, date2)

Obj5 (name5, location7, otherobjectname2, date1, date2)
```

(for a total of about 2600 records, the properties make each record unique)

Basically all of the ObJ objects have at least one property that makes them unique to the collection. So using any groupby, or distinct, or any of the other linq .where clauses I have tried always get me back the entire collection because each record is truly unique.

What I need is to get just one of each object from this overall collection of objects, for a distinct property on the object… i.e. the otherobjectname. See how there are 3 records for one, and then 2 for the other, (I have made a hashset from these otherobjectname, and there are only 975 records).

What I need to get from this collection is just a new collection of MyObjects, where I only have one for each of otherobjectname, and I don’t care which record it is.

So return new List with these in it:

```
Obj1 (name1, location1, otherobjectname1, date1, date2) (I do not care which of the 3)

Obj4 (name4, location6, otherobjectname2, date1, date2) (I do not care which of the 2)
```

And so on for each unique otherobjectname in the collection

Just one unique record for one of the properties on the object
Is there some way to do this? Sorry I can’t really post sample code, I tried to write it out the best I could without using anything specific because of security rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DistinctBy` method (it's not a standard Linq method, but you can find implementations of it in [MoreLinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) or [Linq.Extras](https://github.com/thomaslevesque/Linq.Extras)).

```
var distinct = MyObjects.DistinctBy(x => w.OtherObjectName);
```

Or if you prefer, you can just create a custom equality comparer that only compares the `OtherObjectName` property, and pass it to `Distinct`:

```
class MyObjectComparerByOtherObjectName : IEqualityComparer<MyObject>
{
    public bool Equals(MyObject x, MyObject y)
    {
        return x.OtherObjectName == y.OtherObjectName;
    }

    public bool GetHashCode(MyObject x)
    {
        return x.OtherObjectName != null ? x.OtherObjectName.GetHashCode() : 0;
    }
}

...

var distinct = MyObjects.Distinct(new MyObjectComparerByOtherObjectName());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a group by `otherObjectName` the select the first one from the group like so:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<MyObject> objects = new List<MyObject> {
        new MyObject { name = "name1", locationInfo = "location1", otherObjectName = "otherobjectname1" },
        new MyObject { name = "name2", locationInfo = "location2", otherObjectName = "otherobjectname1" },
        new MyObject { name = "name3", locationInfo = "location3", otherObjectName = "otherobjectname1" },
        new MyObject { name = "name4", locationInfo = "location6", otherObjectName = "otherobjectname2" },
        new MyObject { name = "name5", locationInfo = "location7", otherObjectName = "otherobjectname2" },
    };

    var query = objects.GroupBy(o => o.otherObjectName)
        .Select(g => g.First());

    foreach(var o in query)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", o.name,  o.otherObjectName);
}
```

This returns:

```
name1 otherobjectname1
name4 otherobjectname2
```